# Scipy Z-score returns The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous error

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, boolean, z-score

I am trying to compute the z-score of a ndarray (1x119) and put the results into a new one. But I got the 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous' error.

Here's the code:

```
data = loadmat('data.mat') // return us a dict
ts_1 = data['exp1']
ts_2 = data['exp2']
ts_all = np.concatenate(ts_1,ts_2, axis=1)
ts_all = np.array(ts_all) // useless?

ts_all_z = np.zeros(ts_all.shape)
for i in range(ts_all.shape[1]):
    ts_all_z[:,i] = stats.zscore(ts_all[:,i]) // error
```

I don't understand because I am not doing any boolean comparison...am I?

When looking at ts_all with np.info we get:

class:  ndarray
shape:  (1, 119)
strides:  (952, 8)
itemsize:  8
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  True
data pointer: 0x13b243030
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: object
None

Also, ts_1 and 2 are ndarray of shape (1,22) and (1,24) respectively, of strides (8,8) both.

I think the concatenation is not done correctly? Or the iteration through ts_all shouldn't be done with .shape ...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just copying and pasting your code, and generating a random array of shape `(1,119)` for `ts_all`, the code runs without error. What is the actual shape of `ts_all`?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've added much more detail to the original question and I think you helped me advance @t.o. I believe I'm not doing the concatenation correctly...

Comment: Please read [mre]. The example code is not useful because we do not have the `data.mat` file. Please try making a copy of the file, and reducing the data until you have a small example input that causes the problem; then hard-code that input in the example code. Also, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message - by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting it as multi-line code.

Comment: Thank all for your help I know where the problem comes from! I am trying to compute the z-score of a nd-array but each of the elements don't have the same size! Basically by making an array let's say np.array([6, 7, 7, 12, 13, 13, 15, 16, 19, 22]) the z-score can be computed but if now the array is p.array([[6, 7, 7],
     [12, 13, 13, 15]]) it doesn't work any more! So I'll look into that, again, thanks a lot ! I'll try first z-scoring each of the elements bsaed on its own mean and std and then concatenate, that should work but i'm not sure that's what I want either... ;P

Comment: @CastroPablo glad to hear you found the issue! If you wouldn't mind posting the solution as an answer to this question it could help out people in the future that have similar issues with concatenation

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem but couldn't simply solve it, I had to just find another way of doing. 
The problem seems to be that after concatenation, I have arrays of different size inside the ndarray. 
For instance [[6, 7, 7], [12, 13, 13, 15]]. 
And stats.zscore doesn't like that: it finds it ambiguous because of the size difference: [[6, 7, 7], [12, 13, 13]] **is therefore not an issue**. 
So what I did is simply compute the z scores first, and then concatenate. 
In my case it is fine to do so, but it might not always be the case, for instance, if the concatenation needs to be done before to group the data together so the mean and std can be computed with all the data, then my solution doesn't work. Since each of the concatenated elements are from different experiences, I didn't want to mix the data before z-scoring anyway, I was just trying to make it easier to handle one single ndarray...I was wrong.